# Text search in directory with live preview

Tags: search

How can I text-search the current directory (or any directory) with a live preview? That would be something like ranger or peep-mode but for text-search results. I use counsel-rg mostly, but I have to use `M-RET` on the results to preview. I'd like the preview to happen as I navigate through the lines in the result buffer.

Ideally, the buffers won't stay opened after preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Counsel` provides the commands `ivy-next/previous-line-and-call` for this, which by default [are bound under](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-multiple-selections-and-actions-keep-minibuffer-open) `C-M-n` and `C-M-p`.

Also, for `counsel` this functionality is requested in [this, currently still open, issue](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2800). However, a solution was already suggested [here](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1091#issuecomment-773438243). So for `counsel-rg` you could either create your custom commands, or simply advise `counsel-rg` as follows:

```lisp
(defun my-counsel-rg-preview-advice (orig-fun &rest args)
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
      (lambda () (setq ivy-calling t))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'counsel-rg :around #'my-counsel-rg-preview-advice)
```

Note that `counsel` will find the files for previewing, and 'leaves their buffers open'.

`Consult` and `Helm` both provide configuration options for this by default. See consult `live-preview` [here](https://github.com/minad/consult#live-previews), and `helm-follow-mode` [here](https://rnchzn.github.io/helm/doc/helm-manual.html#Follow-candidates).  `Consult` implemented the feature in a way, that the buffers do not 'stay open', and, although I am not sure, I think `helm` also.